# Copying between servers

Tags: sql-server

I need to copy data from a table on one server to the same table on another server. I tried this:

```
sp_addlinkedserver 'server1' 

INSERT INTO [server2].[R2Op].dbo.[RefR2Ops]
SELECT * FROM server1.[R2Op].dbo.[RefR2Ops]
```

But I am getting an error on the second statement:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

Could you please tell how I can fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: Use an account with access to both servers/map users & logins/grant relevant permissions.

Comment: Is Kerberos set-up? See here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg723715.aspx

Comment: Linked servers need a security context - you need to specify which user is connecting to the remote server. The default is to make the call without using a security context (which uses the anonymous account)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is there. You have not given rights for the local service use to login remote server. You're command is running as default under the rights of NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON.

you need to specfy the user credentials to access the linked server

see [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259581%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
sp_addlinkedsrvlogin [ @rmtsrvname = ] 'rmtsrvname' 
    [ , [ @useself = ] 'useself' ] 
    [ , [ @locallogin = ] 'locallogin' ] 
    [ , [ @rmtuser = ] 'rmtuser' ] 
    [ , [ @rmtpassword = ] 'rmtpassword' ]
```

Comment: I used   

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'server1' 
 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'server1', true, NULL, 'MYNAME', NULL
INSERT INTO [server2].[R2Op].dbo.[RefR2Ops]
SELECT * FROM server1.[R2Op].dbo.[RefR2Ops]
with the same result...

Comment: No, I just use Windows authentication.

Comment: If I apply my windows login information, I get "Login failed for user 'theuser'

Comment: I used SQL Server Import and Export Wizard, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If both servers are in the same ADS domain and your login in present on both servers, you'll probably have to add:

```
  EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'server1', 'true'
```

Otherwise check in which security context the connections to the linked server will be made.